# Angular: Changing path inside event handler not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, event-handling, ng-map

I'm new to angular, and am having a problem changing the location inside of an event handler. The handler is for a marker positioned on a google map. I am using ng-map (which is pretty awesome).

Here's the code that creates the markers (this runs inside the success callback of an $http get):

```
for( i = 0; i < data.Pins.length; i++ )
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: data.Pins[i].StreetAddress,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.Pins[i].Latitude,data.Pins[i].Longitude),
        data: data.Pins[i],
        index: i,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(tgt) {
        $scope.pinClicked(marker);
    });

    marker.setMap($scope.map);

    $scope.markers.push(marker);
}
```

The event handler is very simple:

```
$scope.pinClicked = function(marker) {
    if( marker.data.Homes.length == 1) $location.path("/home");
    else $location.path("/unit");
};
```

When I click on a marker the handler executes, and the if/then/else statement is executed. However, the location does not change.

Is this because I'm outside the "context" for angular because I set up the event listener through google maps?

**Additional Info**

Thanx for the suggestion about using window.location. What I didn't mention earlier is that the map is part of a partial view, so I don't want to trigger a page reload -- I want angular to update the partial view based on a location change. Which I know it can do, because $location.path('/unit') works just fine outside of that event handler.

Comment: try angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: try `$window.location.href = '/unit'` instead,   `$location.path("/unit");` does not trigger a page reload so that might be the issue.

Comment: can you try $scope.$apply after location change.

Comment: do you get any JS error on the console? Because if you are using an angular service outside its scope, you would encounter with an error for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Google Maps event callback runs *outside* the Angular context. Calling `$location.path("...")` is exactly correct (you should **NOT** use `window.location` in an Angular app), but you must use the location service within a callback that's under Angular's control. That's not happening here. Consider this excerpt from your code:

```
$http.get(..., function() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.Pins.length; i++) { // This is your FOR loop 
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(tgt) {
      $scope.pinClicked(marker);
    });
```

The `$http.get()` callback (your function) fires within the Angular context; when your function returns, Angular triggers a $digest cycle, which updates all bindings. It's the $digest cycle that will process any $location changes.

**HOWEVER**... The callback to `google.maps.event.addListener` fires *later*, outside the Angular context. Angular won't see any scope changes or `$location` changes you make within that callback (at least, not immediately—not until the next time a $digest cycle happens to run, whenever that is).

You need to wrap your call to `$scope.pinClicked(marker)` within `$scope.$apply`, like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(tgt) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.pinClicked(marker);
  });
});
```

By wrapping the call in `$scope.$apply`, you've essentially told Angular, "Hey, run the code in this function, and then kick off a $digest cycle."

Comment: Thanx, Brian, that makes perfect sense. I'd come to the same conclusion myself, but didn't realize $apply() can execute a function (my searches generally showed it as being called simply as $scope.apply()).

I was able to work around the problem by using event handlers exposed by ng-map itself (it really is a cool library). It just took a while to dig through the ng-map source code to see how they were named :).

Comment: Calling `$scope.$apply()` (with no arguments) _after_ calling `$scope.pinClicked(marker)` would also work fine. I just prefer the callback version; it seems more elegant and JavaScript-y to me.